# Remove space for css position:relative

Tags: css, position, css-position

I have a link and an iframe side-by-side. I want the link to appear over the iframe. This occurs inside of a td element. this pattern is iterated over a few rows. When I use relative css positioning, I am able to display the link over the iframe, but the space the link would have been in, still appears. and it add unnecessarily to the column height. I want to eliminate this space. How can I do this?

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5689494/298240) but it seems that this solution would still jack up the tr/td height.  I also have a [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/grs53/4/) of my issue

Comment: Let me also make the point that I am working inside of a proprietary framework, and some solutions just aren't available.

Comment: are you talking for height of `#donotwant`?

Comment: Have you tried changing `#top`'s `position:relative` to `position:absolute`. That would remove the extra space above, I don't know how that would affect your page though as you've only shown a snippet.

Comment: take a look at the updated link, i didn't mean to give you only a snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Collapsing the lineheight should do it. Be sure to put a measurement, and not just "0" so it will work in ie6. I added the `.collapse` class to the `div`s containing the anchors. http://jsfiddle.net/grs53/20/

### HTML

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="donotwant">
                <div class="collapse">
                    <a class="top" href="bing.com">link</a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <iframe class="bottom" src="http://www.google.com" ></iframe>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="donotwant">
                <div class="collapse">
                    <a class="top" href="bing.com">link</a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <iframe class="bottom" src="http://www.wikipedia.com" ></iframe>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

### CSS

```
.donotwant {
    border:2px dotted green;
}
.top {
    top:80px;
    left:120px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
    background:red;
}
.bottom {
    position:relative;
    z-index:1
}
.collapse {
    line-height:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your HTML to this

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="donotwant">
                <div class="top">
                    <a href="bing.com">link</a>
                </div>
                <iframe src="http://www.google.com" ></iframe>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="donotwant">
                <div class="top">
                    <a href="bing.com">link</a>
                </div>
                <iframe class="bottom" src="http://www.wikipedia.com" ></iframe>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And you CSS to this:

```
.donotwant {
    border:2px dotted green;
    position:relative;
    height:180px;
    width:300px;
}
.top {
    top:80px;
    left:120px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
}
.bottom {
    position:relative;
    z-index:1
}
```

A relative position object keeps it's initial placement but is displayed elsewhere. An absolute positioned element is actually moved to a new position. You can move absolute positioned elements on top of relative positioned.

In the example above I created a div that is relative positioned in which any absolute position element can be moved around from of the top left corner of the relative positioned element. If the relative positioned element is moved anywhere else on the page the absolute one will follow.

Comment: +1 for beating me to the same answer. Here's the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/grs53/11/

Comment: sorry for not originally posting the right sample but there are multiple rows and position absolute doesn't seem to work for that http://jsfiddle.net/grs53/15/

Answer (score 1):

That unwanted space is from the DIV element you have wrapped around you link. Remove that.

http://jsfiddle.net/saad/grs53/12/

Answer (score 1):

Just collapse the `<div />` that holds the link (e.g. set height to 0). Cross browser might require additional styles but here is [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/grs53/6/) tested in Chrome

Comment: Thanks, but I only changed the css from the original demo. OP has since modified their sample as well